# Syntax highlighter is jumpy lately

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

After entering some code in an answer and the timer expires, the syntax highlighter kicks in and inserts an extra line above the code. Typing some more makes the line disappear. This makes the code jump up and down.

[image][image]

Comment: we did upgrade the syntax highlighter recently so it may be related

Comment: @waffles - any chance this upgrade removed highlight from HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: @Shadow ... possibly, @Geoff is handling it so be sure to raise an issue on meta if there are any other issues you find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We believe this to be fixed now - please let us know if you still see an issue.

Comment: Hey Geoff, I'm seeing issues now in live, HTML syntax highlighting isn't what it used to be...at least that's what appears to be happening. Take a look at anything posted in the last few hours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416327 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416222 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415756  Some questions appear fine, but after several edits and character stripping...I had no luck with those, possibly something changed on the parser side?

Comment: (See also [Code formatting does not work for JavaScript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72037/code-formatting-does-not-work-for-javascript).)

Comment: I'm not getting *any* highlighting in at least some cases, for example, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431863/ksh-script-optimization/4432454#4432454).