# Code formatting does not work for JavaScript

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I think it used to work in the past but now code highlight has no effect on JavaScript whatsover.

jQuery example:

```
$(document).keypress(function (event) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    $("#Container li").each(function (index) {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (text.length > 0 && text.charAt(0).toLowerCase() == key.toLowerCase())
        {
            $("#Container").scrollTop($(this).position().top);
            break;
        }           
    });
});
```

Pure javascript example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        alert("hello" + i);
    }
</script>
```

Has anything changed? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Working fine on SO? Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421786/jquery-live-not-showing-text-cursor-in-firefox But indeed: not here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421540/keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-ul-tag/4421669#4421669

Comment: @Arjan so is this just me? :-/

Comment: I don't think it's just you, I've noticed HTML formatting off the past 2 days as well, something definitely changed...I spent a while yesterday trying to format a post for syntax highlighting for HTML and gave up...when noticed several questions with the same issues - having proper markdown.  This question leads me to believe there were changes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71856/syntax-highlighter-is-jumpy-lately not sure if that was the cause or another symptom of some *other* change.

Comment: @Nick thanks for confirming.. hope some mod will jump by and fix it soon. :)

Comment: @Shadow - tagged it syntax-highlighting as well, hopefully it'll get some love

Comment: @Shadow, I assume the first link in the comment works for you too, but the 2nd does not? So no, it's not just you, but it depends on the post (or more likely: its content). See also the [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/72038#72038).

Comment: @Arjan yep first link show the highlight fine. Wonder how this can be reproduced? Going to mess around in the Sandbox.. :)

Comment: @Shadow, just in case you don't know: the successful highlighting blocks have `<pre class="prettyprint">`, as used by a JavaScript [code prettifier](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html).

Comment: @Arjan cool.. can we add this manually somehow??

Comment: Just add `class="prettyprint"` (like using Firebug, or Chrome's Web Inspector), and then run `javascript:prettyPrint()` in the location bar. That will indeed make your examples work just fine. It seems the `class="prettyprint"` is just lacking in the HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are experimenting with prettify language hints based on tags.  Expect changes and a subsequent meta post outlining this soon.

Comment: Here is the meta post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting

Comment: Cheers, added `javascript` tag to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421540/keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-ul-tag/4421669#4421669 and highlight working as expected. Sweet! :)

Answer (score 2):

Somehow the erroneous blocks are [currently rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJrhb.png) like:

```
<div class="post-text">
  <pre>
    <code>
```

...rather than

```
<div class="post-text">
  <pre class="prettyprint">
    <code>
```

(And the [code prettifier](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) needs that class.)